Is this function differentiable? (Error in the notes?)
So I'm studying in my notes, and there is this "example" (not worked) where it's stated that the following functions is NOT differentiable at $(0, 0)$:
$$f(x, y) = \begin{cases} \frac{\sqrt{x^3} y^3}{x^2+y^4} & (x, y) \neq (0, 0) \\\\ 0 & (x, y) = (0, 0) \end{cases}$$
There is not proof of this, so I thought to work it myself.
I know that if $f$ is not continuous, then it's not differentiable (at a point). But here I already face problems, because studying $f$ along $y = mx$ or $x = y^2$ or $y = x^n$ I always find the limit is zero. Hence it looks continuous.
Then I thought to jump to the definition of differentiability. Observing that $f'_x(0, 0) = 0$ and $f'_y(0, 0) = 0$ I have to check if
$$\vert \frac{f(x, y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \vert $$
goes to zero when $(x, y) \to (0, 0)$.
But again, along every path I follow, I get zero.
Is there by chance an error in the notes, and $f$ is actually differentiable at $(0, 0)$ or is there some subtle detail I'm missing?

How is $\sqrt{x^3}$ defined if $x<0$?

@AnneBauval It's not defined... But I don't understand how it can help, because the term $y^3$ "kills" the term $\sqrt{x^3}$ when $y \to 0$

@AnneBauval On the other side, at points like $(-1, 2)$ the function is not defined. But I don't care of those points, because continuity is requested at the origin...

So, there is no neighborhood of $(0,0)$ on which $f$ is defined, right? Isn't it unusual then to ask whether $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$? And to talk about its partial derivatives at this point?

@AnneBauval But I don't understand: in $\mathbb{R}$ we ask for continuity of $\sqrt{x}$ at $x =0$, and we never mention that it's not defined in a neighbourhood of $0$

Indeed, but that's for continuity. Here we are talking about differentiability.

@AnneBauval Thank you, really. And don't worry for the typo!

@AnneBauval Of course! Have a good night **

This function $f$ is only defined on $[0,\infty)\times\Bbb R$. If we define differentiability of $f$ at $(0,0)$ (which is only on the boundary) by mimicking the usual definition for points interior to the domain, then $f$ is differentiable at this point with differential equal to $0$, since for every $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$ such that $x\ge0$,
$$\frac{|f(x,y)|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\le\frac{x^{3/2}y^2}{x^2+y^4}\le\frac{\sqrt x}2.$$
So, maybe the only reason why your notes say $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$ is that they only allow the usual definition (i.e. at points interior to the domain).

Thank you really much for this!

So I could say that $f$ is not differentiable (in the usual sense) at $(0, 0)$ because $(0, 0)$ is not an internal point?

This was my conclusion.

Thank you again! This was really a "tiny" detail I would have never thought about

Uhm, sorry to bother you again. I was checking online and in many books too, and it NEVER appear that the point must be an internal point. It is only said "a point of the domain", and here $(0, 0)$ belongs to the domain. (Hence it can be a boundary point, internal or even isolated).
Sorry to bother you again, but this really bugs me. Any idea on this?

@Heidegger This is a pretty common confusion. The issue depends on the text, but usually it comes down to the definition of limits in the first place. For example, from the paragraph on page 104 of Spivak's Calculus (2nd edition): "One technical detail [...] deserves some discussion. In order for $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)$ to be defined [...] there must be some $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)$ is defined for $x$ satisfying $0<\vert x-a\vert <\delta$." This technical point then "flows upwards" so that interiority is required for differentiability.

So even though Spivak doesn't explicitly say that functions can only be differentiable at interior points of (the closures of) their domains, this is a consequence of the particular way Spivak interprets the limit definition. I agree it's not as clearly indicated as it could be.

@NoahSchweber Thank you both for the reference and for the clarification. In the end, it looks like it really was because $(0, 0)$ is not an internal point then.

@Heidegger Yup, that's correct. Incidentally, wikipedia (2nd paragraph: "If $x_0$ is an interior point in the domain of a function $f$") is more explicit about this!
